# Using listings package without installing it

Tags: packages, listings, installing

I am finishing writing a paper that uses the `listings` package. Sadly, the submission system I have to use for submitting my paper does not come with this package. Is there any way to use the features available in this package without installing it?

Comment: This might not be a real solution but may be at least a workaround (if it works): I don’t know if this works for TeX, but in HTML for example, you can have CSS definitions in the HTML document itself or in an external .css file. So maybe there is a possibility to copy the whole contents of the listings package into your TeX source so it can be used. Not sure if this is even possible in TeX, though. Just an idea.

Comment: Depends on the features you use. If it is just about nice typesetting of listings, you could go for an approach to typeset them to separate PDFs and include them as images with '\includegraphics`. Packages, such as `standalone` or `preview` might help in this process. If, however, you are using lots of `\lstinline`s this will probably become more painful, even though still doable.

Comment: @brian-ammon While it's possible, in theory, to put the code of a non available package in the document, the listings package would require 9475 lines of code, more or less 400KiB. The code is actually split in subpackages, so it's not only a "paste up" problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are probably allowed to upload more than one file (e.g. also bib-files and input files) why don't you simply add the files of listings to this collection?